# Symfony, Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I try to install Sonata Admin with my Symfony. I follow the instruction of the link http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html.

I choose file format is admin.yml. When I run 
php app/console assets:install

I got the error 
[image]

Here are my admin.yml

## Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your extension file DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\DemobundleExtension (or whatever you named it), you should load the configuration file with Loader\YamlFileLoader, you are probably doing it with Loader\XmlFileLoader

```
class DemobundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('admin.yml');        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I change it to admin.xml and it works. Thanks for your help